# How do I deal with a problem file in an Inbound File Synchronizer

Tags: java, spring, ftp, spring-integration

I have an ftp inbound file synchronizer.

What is happening is summarised in this stack trace:

```
failure occurred in messaging taskjava.io.IOException: Failed to copy 'ANI Feeds/2019/ANI Pictures/07/24/20190724057C-tokyo-governor-koike-tokyo-2020-president-mori-ioc-president-bach-and-japans-pm-abe-attend-the-one-year-to-go-ceremony-celebrating-one-year-out-from-the-start-of-the-summer-games-in-tokyo.txt'. Server replied with: 550 "ANI Feeds/2019/ANI Pictures/07/24/20190724057C-tokyo-governor-koike-tokyo-2020-president-mori-ioc-president-bach-and-japans-pm-abe-attend-the-one-year-to-go-ceremony-celebrating-one-year-out-from-the-start-of-the-summer-games-in-tokyo.txt": no such file.

    at org.springframework.integration.ftp.session.FtpSession.read(FtpSession.java:85) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.copyRemoteContentToLocalFile(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:443) ~[na:na]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failure occurred while copying 'ANI Feeds/2019/ANI Pictures/07/24/20190724057C-tokyo-governor-koike-tokyo-2020-president-mori-ioc-president-bach-and-japans-pm-abe-attend-the-one-year-to-go-ceremony-celebrating-one-year-out-from-the-start-of-the-summer-games-in-tokyo.txt' from the remote to the local directory; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Failed to copy 'ANI Feeds/2019/ANI Pictures/07/24/20190724057C-tokyo-governor-koike-tokyo-2020-president-mori-ioc-president-bach-and-japans-pm-abe-attend-the-one-year-to-go-ceremony-celebrating-one-year-out-from-the-start-of-the-summer-games-in-tokyo.txt'. Server replied with: 550 "ANI Feeds/2019/ANI Pictures/07/24/20190724057C-tokyo-governor-koike-tokyo-2020-president-mori-ioc-president-bach-and-japans-pm-abe-attend-the-one-year-to-go-ceremony-celebrating-one-year-out-from-the-start-of-the-summer-games-in-tokyo.txt": no such file.

    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.copyRemoteContentToLocalFile(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:450) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.copyFileToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:406) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.transferFilesFromRemoteToLocal(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:342) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.lambda$synchronizeToLocalDirectory$0(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:309) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.RemoteFileTemplate.execute(RemoteFileTemplate.java:437) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:308) ~[na:na]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Wrapped by: org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Problem occurred while synchronizing 'ANI Feeds/2019/ANI Pictures/07/24' to local directory; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failure occurred while copying 'ANI Feeds/2019/ANI Pictures/07/24/20190724057C-tokyo-governor-koike-tokyo-2020-president-mori-ioc-president-bach-and-japans-pm-abe-attend-the-one-year-to-go-ceremony-celebrating-one-year-out-from-the-start-of-the-summer-games-in-tokyo.txt' from the remote to the local directory; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Failed to copy 'ANI Feeds/2019/ANI Pictures/07/24/20190724057C-tokyo-governor-koike-tokyo-2020-president-mori-ioc-president-bach-and-japans-pm-abe-attend-the-one-year-to-go-ceremony-celebrating-one-year-out-from-the-start-of-the-summer-games-in-tokyo.txt'. Server replied with: 550 "ANI Feeds/2019/ANI Pictures/07/24/20190724057C-tokyo-governor-koike-tokyo-2020-president-mori-ioc-president-bach-and-japans-pm-abe-attend-the-one-year-to-go-ceremony-celebrating-one-year-out-from-the-start-of-the-summer-games-in-tokyo.txt": no such file.

    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.java:315) ~[na:na]
    at com.afrozaar.ashes.ingestor.ani.CustomFtpInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory(CustomFtpInboundFileSynchronizer.java:23) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:258) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.file.remote.synchronizer.AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractInboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractFetchLimitingMessageSource.doReceive(AbstractFetchLimitingMessageSource.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractMessageSource.receive(AbstractMessageSource.java:160) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:250) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:360) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:329) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$null$1(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:277) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50) ~[spring-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$2(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:274) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:93) ~[spring-context-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
```

In case you didn't see the root error:

```
Server replied with: 550 "ANI Feeds/2019/ANI Pictures/07/24/20190724057C-tokyo-governor-koike-tokyo-2020-president-mori-ioc-president-bach-and-japans-pm-abe-attend-the-one-year-to-go-ceremony-celebrating-one-year-out-from-the-start-of-the-summer-games-in-tokyo.txt": no such file.
```

So the ftp failure gets spewed out but the problem is that there's no way around this error. Because of this error this exception is thrown permanently - i.e on every poll as the file cannot be loaded so is never put in the metadata store.

What I'm wanting to know is how do I "swallow" this error and move onto the next file?

I do suspect it is because of the size of the filename. Ftp is not downloading it because it is too big. It is there, as it was found when the directory was scanned but when it comes to download it, this fails.

Comment: Spaces could be a problem, how about `ANI%20Feeds/2019/ANI%20Pictures...`? or `ANI\ Feeds/2019/ANI\ Pictures...`

Answer (score 0):

You could manually add the bad file to the `MetadataStore`.

Or you can subclass the filter, overriding `rollback()` to skip the first file in the rollback list.

Unfortunately, though, `rollback()` has no information about why the rollback is executed so this would always skip the first file, even for other errors.